# Why does OpenGL run on some phones but not on others?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, surfaceview, textures

I have the following code for my Renderer:

```
package hello.project;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;

public class HelloOpenGLES10Renderer implements Renderer {

    private Square      square;
    private Square2     square2;
    private Square3     square3;
    private SquareAccesories        squareAcc;
    private SquareEyes      squareEyes;
    private SquareLips      squareLips;
    private SquarePants     squarePants;
    private SquareShoes     squareShoes;
    private Context     context;
    //public static int w,h;


    /** Constructor to set the handed over context */
    public HelloOpenGLES10Renderer(Context context) {
        this.square     = new Square();
        this.square2        = new Square2();
        this.square3        = new Square3();
        this.squareAcc      = new SquareAccesories();
        this.squareEyes     = new SquareEyes();
        this.squareLips     = new SquareLips();
        this.squarePants        = new SquarePants();
        this.squareShoes        = new SquareShoes();
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        if (Project.ifDraw){
            Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
            Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair());
            Square3.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square3.getDress());
            SquareAccesories.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareAccesories.getAcc());
            SquareEyes.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareEyes.getEyes());
            SquareLips.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareLips.getLips());
            SquarePants.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquarePants.getPants());
            SquareShoes.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareShoes.getShoes());
            Project.ifDraw=false;
        }
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
        //GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)w / (float)h, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 1, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);
        square.draw(gl);
        square2.draw(gl);
        square3.draw(gl);
        squareEyes.draw(gl);
        squareAcc.draw(gl);
        squareLips.draw(gl);
        squareShoes.draw(gl);
        squarePants.draw(gl);

        /*// clear Screen and Depth Buffer
        Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
        Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair()); 
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);   
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Reset the Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        // Drawing
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);  // move 5 units INTO the screen
        square.draw(gl);
        square2.draw(gl);*/ 
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
            height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
        }

        //w=width;
        //h=height;
        //Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
        //Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair()); 
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

        //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Mode   lview Matrix
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Load the texture for the square
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);    //Enable Smooth Shading
        //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        //gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        //Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
        //Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair());
        //Square3.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square3.getDress());
        //SquareAccesories.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareAccesories.getAcc());
        //SquareEyes.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareEyes.getEyes());
        //SquareLips.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareLips.getLips());
        //SquarePants.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquarePants.getPants());
        //SquareShoes.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,SquareShoes.getShoes());
        //gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0.5f);

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //Black Background
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);      //Depth Buffer Setup
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_NEVER);    //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

        //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
    }
}
```

On the emulator, it works perfect. I used an Xperia Play for debugging, and also tried it on an HTC xplorer and Galaxy Nexus, and it worked.
2day i tried it on a Samsung Galaxy and an HTC phone but the SurfaceView did not show nothing, it was blank, any ideeas why this could happen?

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't work for you, but you shouldn't be loading textures in the draw method. Preload them before starting to draw and reuse them, this would speed things up nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made the pictures dimensions powers of 2 and know it works